# is it possible to export react developed dashboard as png or svg and share via mail

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for solution is it possible to export reactjs dashboard content as PNG or SVG and share via mail with share button.

How to put a share button on the react.js page. Clicking on the share button will open mail for sharing the current Dom as PNG or SVG

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpxGQ.png

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Please read [ask]. SO is not a place where you can ask for code. If that's what you need, you should consider hiring a developer. Think of [SO] as a place where you can ask questions like: I wrote this code and I'm expecting it to do this thing but it does something else (or nothing), although the docs (with link) say it should do what I expect it to.
Getting back to your question: where is your code?